# Как называется структура базы данных

Tags: база-данных, архитектура

В базе данных нужно хранить объекты у которых переменно число атрибутов. В том числе атрибутом может быть другой объект. Соответственно а базе данных создаётся таблица с атрибутами объекта.
При этом сам объект описывается в приложении любым доступным способом.

Как называется такая структура (архитектура) базы данных? И нет ли на неё стандарта? Буду признателен за какую-нибудь статью.

Comment: Уж не про EAV ли Вы ведёте речь?

Comment: Поищите, кстати, по сайту это слово. Наверняка найдете что-то полезное - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=EAV+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы описываете, вполне укладывается в паттерн [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) (Entity-Attribute-Value).

При этом подходе создается таблица для объектов (Entity), словарь атрибутов (Attribute) и таблица значений атрибутов объектов (Value).

Если атрибуты могут быть разных типов, то словарь атрибутов описывает также и тип данных каждого атрибута, а таблица значений имеет отдельный столбец под каждый тип данных или один столбец универсального типа. Одной из разновидностей типов данных вполне может быть внешний ключ на таблицу объектов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Никак она не называется, так как это обычное проектирование таблиц, где используется таблица, хранящая атрибуты объектов. Единственным стандартом для данного случая могут являться так называемые **нормальные формы**, которые призваны избавить вашу базу данных от аномалий разного рода: вставки, удаления и т.п.